# SignTool Error: WinVerifyTrust returned error: 0x80096019

Tags: windows, certificate, clickonce, code-signing, signtool

After signing my Application using Test certificate (pfx) with signtool when I try to verify using signtool verify I am getting below error code

```
SignTool Error: WinVerifyTrust returned error: 0x80096019
    A certificate's basic constraint extension has not been observed.
```

I have Tried to other exe with the same cert still the same Issue?

I have tried different certificates with the same exe still the same Issue?

I have searched on the Internet I couldn't find a source or Link. Any Help would be much appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

You maybe use a CA certificate to sign. A CA certificate should issue a Code Signing certificate so you need a second certificate to sign your executable (Basic Constraints = LIMITED to 0 or false) that is then used to sign the executable.
This second code signing certificate is signed with the CA certificates private key.

[image: Cert signer path]